# GreenDroid Actionbar Text

Tags: android, greendroid

I use greendroid to implement to actionbar under api 11.

Now i have a strange behaviour in my MainView (the startview works well)

```
public class MainView extends GDActivity {

    private boolean ison = false;
    private FinderThread finder; 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


     //this.getActionBar().removeViewAt(0);
    setActionBarContentView(R.layout.mainlayout);
    getActionBar().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#bf27c3"));

    setTitle("TEST");  
    setTitleColor(Color.WHITE);
    addActionBarItem(getActionBar().newActionBarItem(NormalActionBarItem.class).setDrawable(R.drawable.person));
```

Looking:

[image]

The Actionbar text is empty and no home button. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to set the Title and the Color of the Title with

`getActionBar().setTitle("Title")`

The same for the color. Try also to set the color via an RGB value.

I can't promise that this will work, because i don't use greendroid for my actionbars. But i understand that you don't use actionbarsherlock + greendroid because they are only compatible with a trick (a bit hacking xD)